Python response.content contains page text, not file
I am attempting to use python to automate the conversion of a file using an existing webpage.  The page in question allows a user to upload a csv file, performs a conversion, prompts the user to save a zip file containing the converted file, and then re-renders the page.  It has the following HTML form:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="zips" method="post">
<input type='file' name='filestozip[]' id='filetozip' multiple />
<input type='submit' name='createzip' value="Perform Conversion" onclick="resetErrorBox();" />
</form>

Most of the python examples demonstrate either upload of a file or download, but not both.  My particular issue is accessing the resulting zip content.
My python code is:
import requests

url = 'http://the.webpage.com'
local_file_path = 'C:\\the\\path\\to\\my\\file.csv'
output_file_path = 'C:\\the\\path\\to\\my\\output.zip'

upload_file = {'filestozip[]': (local_file_path, open(local_file_path, 'rb'), 'text/csv')}

response = requests.post(url, files=upload_file)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.output)

upload_file['filestozip[]'][1].close()


The response status code is 200 and the output.zip is written.  However, it is not a valid zip and contains the HTML of the webpage.  I'm sure I am making a simple mistake, but how can I capture the zip file?
Thanks in advance.
